# CSS triangle shape with a curved corner

Tags: css

When I write this CSS to a create a triangle shape, it works as below with sharp edges:

```
.triangle { 
border-left: 70px solid transparent; 
border-bottom: 70px solid #f4a234; 
float: left; 
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); 
margin-top: 12px; 
margin-left: 12px; 
}
```

When I add a radius for only a corner, as below, it converts from a triangle into a square shape. I am newbie in HTML/CSS and need help to keep it shown as a triangle but with 1 rounded corner.

```
.triangle { 
border-left: 70px solid transparent; 
border-bottom: 70px solid #f4a234; 
float: left; 
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); 
margin-top: 12px; 
margin-left: 12px; 
border-bottom-right-radius: 12px; 
}
```

Comment: Hi! I [created this example for you](http://jsbin.com/moyufeweqeri/1/edit) that gives you the result that you want :) The square is caused by the orange border rendering differently and overflowing underneath the transparent border when `border-radius` is used. We can compensate with `overflow:hidden` and rotation.

Comment: I'm afraid that my example only seems to work in Chrome, but could still lead you in the right direction.